# Re-templating built in WPF controls using Visual State Manager

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, vsm

I am developing an application in WPF and would like to use to re-template built in controls (Button,ListBox, etc) using the VSM instead of triggers.

Is there a built in way to do this? Anyone have any implementation strategies they'd like to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does seem to be some built in support.  I am using .NET 4.0 and the Feb 2010 version of the toolkit.  I copied a Silverlight template and replaced it with the default button template and it seems to work so far.